# how to create an array that store values and populate it in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm a noob in Ruby and I need some help with my code.

I'm just  at finding how to create an array to store the values and then display it. Right now my code shows how much interest in accumulated depending on how many years and savings you had in the beginning. Now i want it to show if I were to put 5 years that it will display an array how much each year, within those 5 years, it added in interest; example 3 years[3367.34, 3401.01, 3435.02] (these values are of 1% interest)

**My code:**

```
puts "How much would you like to save?"
savings = gets.chomp.to_f 

puts "For how long would you like to save it for?"
time = gets.chomp.to_i

(savings > 0 || true) && (time > 0 || true)

i = 0.01 

counter = 1 

until counter > time do
account = Hash.new

savings = (savings + savings * i)

account["Your account"] = savings.to_f.round(2)

counter += 1

end
account.each { |savings| puts "Interest calculated over #{time} years #{savings}" }
```

**Added**
I just added this portion to my code, and it does generate an array but not sure how to adjust so that it can put the value of interest that is added to savings (over the amount of years user wants) with in the array. Ex: if I were to put 3 years the answer should look something like this ==> savings = array[3367.34, 3401.01, 3435.02] each amount represents that interest accumulated for that year (1styr) = 3367.34 (2ndyr)3401.01 (3rdyr) 3435.02

```
> puts "how much will you save?"
>     n=gets.to_i
>     array= Array(0..n)
>     puts array.inspect
```

Comment: There is no error, i just don't know get an output of an array displaying each years interest added to the savings. @maxpleaner

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get the savings info into an array, but honestly, there's still enough other issues with your code that this will not solve all the problems.

```
array = []
until counter > time do

   savings = (savings + savings * i)

   array << savings.to_f.round(2) # this pushes the new value onto your array

   counter += 1
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I need to know how to get multiple amounts into the array. ex: if I were to put 3 years the answer should look something like this ==> ["Your Account" = >3367.34, 3401.01, 3435.02] each amount represents that interest accumulated for that year (1styr) = 3367.34 (2ndyr)3401.01 (3rdyr) 3435.02 @bek